# Custom Psuedo Selector not working in ExtJS

Tags: javascript, extjs

I am trying to create an use a custom pseudo selector in ExtJS to perform a case-insensative search.  However, I keep getting this error:

> Uncaught TypeError: Object # has no method 'containsIgnoreCase'

Here is the JSFiddle (the results are logged in the console):

http://jsfiddle.net/k4ggq/9/

Here is the JavaScript:

```
Ext.ComponentQuery.pseudos.containsIgnoreCase = function(n, i, m) {
    return Ext.get(n).dom.innerText.toUpperCase().indexOf(m[3].toUpperCase()) >= 0;
};

var showEls = Ext.query('.serviceGridItem:containsIgnoreCase(mytext)');
```

How can I create this pseudo selector?

Ref. http://www.objis.com/formationextjs/lib/extjs-4.0.0/docs/api/Ext.ComponentQuery.html

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like you're trying to use ComponentQuery when what you want is a DomQuery. The former allows you to select Ext.Component classes in the current page, where as the latter selects DOM elements.

```
Ext.DomQuery.pseudos.containsIgnoreCase = function(elems, strToMatch) {
    var results = [], ri = -1;
    strToMatch = new RegExp(strToMatch, "ig");
    for(var i = 0, len = elems.length; i < len; i++){
        var dom = Ext.get(elems[i]).dom;
        if(strToMatch.test(dom.textContent) || strToMatch.test(dom.innerText)){
            results.push(elems[i]);
        }
    }
    return results;
};
```

The above should work - note that innerText doesn't work in Firefox hence the two tests.

See http://jsfiddle.net/Ep29Q/ for an updated example

Comment: Thanks, man!  Still learning ExtJS - wish I was using jQuery :)